# How to find the type of a typedArray?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typed-arrays

To test if an object is an array, there is a method -

```js
const myarray = [1,2,3,4]; 
Array.isArray(myarray); 
//returns true
```

Is there a similar method for typed arrays (for example, Uint8Array)?

```js
const int8 = new Uint8Array([0,1,2,3]);
Array.isArray(int8); //returns false
```

How can I find out if an object is a typed array, and what kind of typed array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a comparison with its constructor <sup>**1**</sup>:

```js
const int8 = new Uint8Array([0,1,2,3]);
console.log(int8.constructor === Uint8Array);

// so you can do
function checkTypedArrayType(someTypedArray) {
  const typedArrayTypes = [
    Int8Array,
    Uint8Array,
    Uint8ClampedArray,
    Int16Array,
    Uint16Array,
    Int32Array,
    Uint32Array,
    Float32Array,
    Float64Array,
    BigInt64Array,
    BigUint64Array
  ];
  const checked = typedArrayTypes.filter(ta => someTypedArray.constructor === ta);
  return checked.length && checked[0].name || null;
}

console.log(checkTypedArrayType(int8));

// but this can be hugely simplified
function checkTypedArrayType2(someTypedArray) {
  return someTypedArray && 
    someTypedArray.constructor && 
    someTypedArray.constructor.name || 
    null;
}

console.log(checkTypedArrayType2(int8));

// which can actually be generalized to
const whatsMyType = someObject => 
  someObject && 
    someObject.constructor && 
    someObject.constructor.name && 
    someObject.constructor.name || 
    null;

console.log(whatsMyType(int8));
console.log(whatsMyType([1,2,3,4]));
console.log(whatsMyType("hello!"))
console.log(whatsMyType(/[a-z]/i))
```

<sup>**1**</sup> Note that no version of Internet Explorer supports the `name` property. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). [See also](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23317/istypeobj-gettypeobj-v0/23329#23329)

Answer (score 2):

There is actually an equivalent to *Array.isArray* for TypedArrays, accessible on the `ArrayBuffer` constructor:

[`ArrayBuffer.isView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/isView).

However note that it will also return true for *DataView* objects, so if you really want to know if an object is a TypedArray, you can simply do:

```js
function isTypedArray( arr ) {
  return ArrayBuffer.isView( arr ) && !(arr instanceof DataView);
}

function test( val ) {
  console.log( isTypedArray( val ) );
}

test( false ); // false
test( null ); // false
test( [] ); // false
test( new ArrayBuffer( 12 ) ); // false
test( new DataView( new ArrayBuffer( 12 ) ) ); // false
test( new Uint8Array( 12 ) ); // true;
test( new BigInt64Array( 12 ) ); // true;
```

But this won't give you the particular type of that TypedArray.

TypedArray's prototype exposes a [`BYTES_PER_ELEMENT`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typedarray.prototype.bytes_per_element) property, but that's about it...

There is a [`.name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/name) accessible on the constructor, which is itself accessible through the `.constructor` property of each instance, but that can be set and is not supported by IE. But if it's not a problem for you all it takes is:

```js
function getType( arr ) {
  return isTypedArray( arr ) && arr.constructor.name;
}
function isTypedArray( arr ) {
  return ArrayBuffer.isView( arr ) && !(arr instanceof DataView);
}

function test( val ) {
  console.log( getType( val ) );
}

test( [] ); // false
test( new ArrayBuffer( 12 ) ); // false
test( new DataView( new ArrayBuffer( 12 ) ) ); // false
test( new Uint8Array( 12 ) ); // "Uint8Array";
test( new BigInt64Array( 12 ) ); // "BigInt64Array";
```

And if you need to support IE, testing all possible TypedArrays Constructors independently with `instanceof` is also an option:

```js
const typedArrays = [
 'Int8',
 'Uint8',
 'Uint8Clamped',
 'Int16',
 'Uint16',
 'Int32',
 'Uint32',
 'Float32',
 'Float64',
 'BigInt64',
 'BigUint64'
].map( (pre) => pre + 'Array' );

function getType( arr ) {
  return isTypedArray( arr ) &&
    typedArrays.find( (type) => arr instanceof window[ type ] );
}

function isTypedArray( arr ) {
  return ArrayBuffer.isView( arr ) && !(arr instanceof DataView);
}

function test( val ) {
  console.log( getType( val ) );
}

test( [] ); // false
test( new Uint8Array( 12 ) ); // Uint8Array
test( new Int16Array( 12 ) ); // Int16Array
test( new Float32Array( 12 ) ); // Float32Array
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be, You could make use of **`BYTES_PER_ELEMENT`** property of a typed Array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/BYTES_PER_ELEMENT

```
Array.isTypedArray = function(inArray) {
  if (inArray) {
    const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(inArray);
    return prototype ? prototype.hasOwnProperty("BYTES_PER_ELEMENT") : false;
  }
  return false;
};
```

As mentioned in other answers, to get the actual type you can use the `constructor.name`. Reusing the above `isTypedArray` function, you could write like.

```
function getType(obj){
    return Array.isTypedArray(obj) ? obj.constructor.name: (typeof obj)
}
```

Sample code & console.logs

```js
Array.isTypedArray = function(inArray){
    if(inArray){
        const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(inArray);
        return prototype ? prototype.hasOwnProperty("BYTES_PER_ELEMENT") : false;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(" 'Iam' a typed array  ", Array.isTypedArray([1,2,3]));
console.log("[1,2,3] is typed array  ", Array.isTypedArray([1,2,3]));
console.log("new Int8Array([1,2,3]) is typed array  ", Array.isTypedArray(new Int8Array([1,2,3])));
console.log("new BigUint64Array() is typed array  ", Array.isTypedArray(new BigUint64Array()));
console.log("new Uint8ClampedArray([1,2,3]) is typed array  ", Array.isTypedArray(new Uint8ClampedArray([1,2,3])));
console.log("new Float32Array([1,2,3]) is typed array  ", Array.isTypedArray(new Float32Array([1,2,3])));
console.log("new BigUint64Array() is typed array  ", Array.isTypedArray(new BigUint64Array()));
console.log("new Set() is typed array  ", Array.isTypedArray(new Set()));
console.log("null is typed array  ", Array.isTypedArray(null));
console.log("undedined is typed array  ", Array.isTypedArray(undefined));
console.log("{} is typed array  ",Array.isTypedArray({}));


function getType(obj){
    return Array.isTypedArray(obj) ? obj.constructor.name: (typeof obj)
}

console.log("Type of Array  ", getType(new Array()));
console.log("Type of Int8Array  ", getType(new Int8Array()));
console.log("Type of Uint8Array  ",getType( new Uint8Array()));
console.log("Type of Uint8ClampedArray  ",getType( new Uint8ClampedArray()));
console.log("Type of Int16Array  ", getType(new Int16Array()));
console.log("Type of Float32Array  ", getType(new Float32Array()));
console.log("Type of BigInt64Array  ", getType(new BigInt64Array()));
console.log("Type of BigUint64Array  ", getType(new BigUint64Array()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.name` property on it. It should return the type: "Uint8Array". This works with Uint16 and Unint32's as well.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/name

Edit: adding source

Comment: This is only available on the Constructor, not the instance

Comment: @Kaiido given an instance, you can acquire the constructor
.

Comment: @AluanHaddad sure, I never said the contrary, but saying "You can use the `.name` property **on it.**" is a lie.

Comment: @Kaiido that's true. The author should revise this. Without relying on the constructor `new Uint16Array()[Symbol.toStringTag] === "Uint16Array"`